# Как сделать чтоб результат в numericUpDown не округлялся?

Tags: c#, winforms

Например numericUpDown1 умножается на numericUpDown2 и результат в numericUpDown1: если 49 * 1,18 = 57,82, тогда если в numericUpDown1 decimalplaces = 0, результат округляется и в numericUpDown1 будет 58. Если decimalplaces = 2, в результате в numericUpDown1 будет 57,82. Как сделать чтоб при decimalplaces = 0, результат не округлялся? Или чтоб в примере 49 * 1,18 в результате в numericUpDown1 было = 57?

Comment: +1 за слово "заукругливался" `Math.Floor(numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
numericUpDown1.Value = Math.Floor(numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value);
```

*Update*

> как сделать чтоб результат округлялся также только до десятых

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx

```
numericUpDown1.Value = Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value, 1);
```

*Update*

> Нужно сделать метод Math.Floor, только не для целых чисел, а для
>   десятых.

```
numericUpDown1.Value = Math.Floor(numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value * 10) / 10;
```

Comment: а как сделать чтоб результат округлялся также только до десятых? Например: 49 * 1,18 чтоб в результате округлялись десятые  до 57,8 ?

Comment: неправильно выразился. Нужно сделать метод Math.Floor, только не для целых чисел, а для десятых. Например: нужно чтоб при 49 * 1,21 = 59,29 чтоб в результате было 59,2. (То есть чтоб не округляло десятые) (По ссылке смотрел, не нашел подходящего метода)